# getting the value from url using # from javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, javascript-objects

In my search option I redirect my URL to

> window.location = '/admin/#q='+value+'&type='+type;

Now I want to take the value of q & type from URL

P.s. due to my url-rewrite rule I can't use ? instead of #

Answer (score 3):

Use javascript `split('&')` on `window.location.hash` to separate the key/value pairs, then `split('=')` to separate key from value, check if `key=='type'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain and modify the value after the `#` via `window.location.hash`. Note that depending on the browser there may or may not be a leading `#` sign.